# How to hash multiple passwords at once, efficiently?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hash

I have a mysql table with columns userid, password, hashedpassword.   I used to store passwords as plain text in the password column. I now realize that is unacceptable and want to now hash all of them and store them the right way in the hashedpassword field.

You're going to get mad at the script below because it's horrifically inefficient.  As you might guess, it timed out on my server.  Can someone help an obviously inexperienced programmer with the proper way to update all of these fields in the database? Clearly connecting to the database for EACH record is idiotic :(...

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM users";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
            if (!$result) {
            die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
            } else {
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $userid=$row['userid'];
                    $passwordhashed=password_hash($row['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    $sql = "UPDATE users
                        SET hashedpassword='$passwordhashed'
                        WHERE userid='$userid'
                        LIMIT 1";
                            $update = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                            if (!$update) {
                            die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
                            } else {
                                //we good
                            }

                }

            }
```

Comment: why it have to be at once? you can execute multiple updates separately and I think it will be more efficient.  Is there any reason why should be at once?

Comment: most likely this is just a one time thing, so just loop users with their passwords, hash and everyting, then create an sql string, or a file then just execute it in a terminal

Comment: its a one off job, whats it matter how long it will take

Comment: "Clearly connecting to the database for EACH record is idiotic" you don't, you do one select then one update per user all using one connection. which is correct

Comment: You're right Dagon, it's a one off job that I won't need to do ever again. But my server keeps crapping out.  I kept getting a fatal error, 30 seconds max execution time.  So I tried adding "ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes" per another suggestion and it went a little longer but eventually crapped out again.  Was just wondering if there was a more efficient way to do it to avoid server timeouts or anything

Comment: Don't run long running jobs via a web server! Log into your server via SSH or what have you and run `$ php update_all_passwords.php` on the command line. There is no timeout there (usually). If you have no clue what any of what I just wrote means, it's about time to figure it out. :o)

Comment: If SSH is not an option, you can also simply: 1) take a dump of the database, 2) hash all the passwords on your local machine (on the command line, not web server), 3) create the appropriate MySQL queries to update your database, 4) upload and execute those on your server.

Comment: how many do you get through in 5 minutes? and how many do you have to do?

Comment: a common problem in the beginning is wanting to do things all at once. you don't need to do that. go ahead and apply a divide and conquer strategy to your problem.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. In this case you'd add two placeholders `?` to represent the data.

Answer (score 0):

out of curiosity how many users rows do you have in your table?

I worked a system on mine made a while back when upgrading to the `password_hash` function (from -  similarly- unwise plain text storage) whereby I made a script to update the password with a new one, using this hashing method.

The difference is deployment - I emailed all clients (~1600) and told them to click the link in the email to update their password as a precaution, entering their current password and a new (different) password, therefore each password is individually updated ***AND*** the plain text password is not used as a hashed password, if someone already has a copy of your table and can look up the plain text passwords then just converting them to hashes will not lock that door, instead they can still get in and mess around on the users accounts.

(*And in case you think "oh it's ok no one will have a copy of my table",  this thought-logic will also mean that you don't need to encrypt your plain text passwords in the first place!* -- MySQL can be hacked and you need not know about it if the hacker is careful and considerate rather than someone showing off their spamhack skills)

This also will mean only clients who did not follow the emailed advise would be at risk from any current or future breach. I also included similar conversion code to the site login, forcing a new password selection in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Your general strategy here is correct. If you're having time-out issues, that might not be a problem with the code but how you're running it.

Is running this script through the command-line an option? That doesn't have an intrinsic time-out like a web request does. Normally you execute long-running migration scripts in this fashion because it's expected they'll take way longer than a usual page render.

Another thing to consider is creating a single [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and then executing that multiple times. A prepared statement serves as a template for your query, and when properly bound and executed can operate on different records each time. This is usually faster than sending different statements for each query.

The `password_hash` function is intentionally slow. Running this on thousands of users will take a lot of time, there's no way around that. The reason it's far more secure than things like MD5 is due to the computational cost of hashing.

It's worth noting that the `LIMIT 1` in your `UPDATE` should be unnecessary since you're scoping this to `userid` which *should* have a `UNIQUE` constraint.

I'll add that if you want to this properly you'd be using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/)
like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) since most of those come with some kind of [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in. Rolling your own is extremely risky as I'm sure you're starting to discover.